# libclang slow reparsing of translation unit

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang

I have a c++ file which changes and rest all headers files remain unchanged. But whenever I re-parse a translation unit, libclang ends up consuming lots of cpu and ram. Although it is using precompiled header and all (I can see preamble files generated) but still it takes quite bit of resources as well as time.

Here is the snippet of my code.

```
translation_unit_ = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index_, 0, clang_argv[0],
    clang_argv.size() - 1, 0, 0,
    clang_defaultEditingTranslationUnitOptions()); 
// File name is in the arguments.


// Here I reparse again every time file changes.
clang_reparseTranslationUnit(translation_unit_, 0, 0,
    clang_defaultReparseOptions(translation_unit_));

// This is how I get diagnositics
CXDiagnostic diag = clang_getDiagnostic(translation_unit_, i);
```

Can anyone suggest me right setup for finding compile errors in a single changing source file repeatedly?

Comment: Is your goal to simply find compile errors? Or do you also want high-quality optimized and minimized code output?

Comment: Just to find compile errors and code completions!

Answer (score 1):

You're using `clang_defaultEditingTranslationUnitOptions()` in the initial indexing and `clang_defaultReparseOptions()` later. Try using `clang_defaultEditingTranslationUnitOptions()`in both places.

Also, don't expect reparsing the source to be extremely quick - rechecking every single change *will* lead to poor performance in any non-trivial source file. Can you wait a few milliseconds after the last change, to see if you can accumulate multiple changes into a single reparse?